# US Port of Entry

Tags: visas, usa, india, layovers, b1-b2-visas

I'm traveling from New Delhi to New York, and have Boston as a 2.5 hour layover. In the DS-160 form for B1/B2 Visa, I've filled New York as my entry to the US. Will this be problematic for my Visa approval?

Comment: You are fine. Nothing unusual about that.

Answer (score 7):

If your Visa was approved, it is for the USA, not for a specific port of entry.

It doesn't matter which airport you enter on (or which sea port or street crossing), as long as your activities are within the limits of the visa.

Comment: But it's not approved yet, I've a pending interview. I've booked a refundable flight because it will get expensive by the time my Visa gets approved.

Comment: @Sam Chats Just an opinion, but if they’re going to refuse your application it would surely be for a stronger reason than planning to enter via Boston instead of New York.

Comment: US visas almost never specify a required port of entry. If there is such a restriction, it will be printed on the visa. But this is a one in a million sort of thing. You are not likely to ever see it on your visa.

Comment: @SamChats as I understand it, you're supposed to put an "arrival city" in your DS-160 if you've made specific plans or if you can provide an *estimated* itinerary.  Changing the travel plans is no problem by itself.  Anyway, "arrival city" is arguably different than "port of entry."  As long as your plans are reasonable and do not raise suspicion of deception, of status violation, or of grounds of inadmissibility, small or even large changes are no problem.  Furthermore, booking a flight to NYC with a layover in Boston barely even qualifies as a change.

Comment: Thanks a lot everyone for all this info. I'm assured now that this won't be a big deal during the interview. By the way, will the consular officer ask for my flight itinerary during the interview? I'll keep a printout with me just to be on the safe side.

Comment: @Aganju can you please summarise all this information in the answer, I'll mark it as accepted then (already upvoted it!)

Comment: @SamChats, yes, it is likely that the officer will ask for your flight itinerary. It is wise to keep such papers (or copies of them) with you during your stay in the US, especially if you travel to states in the Southern US regions. Just beware of pickpockets (thieves).